# Calculate confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I wanted to calculate a confidence interval of 95% for an specific parameter beta using the function `intervals(object,level,...)`

but marks an error that says

> Error in UseMethod("intervals"): no applicable method for 'intervals'
>   applied to an object of class "lm"

It should have not mark any error because in the `help` section says clearly that this function is for Confidence intervals on the parameters associated with the model represented by object are obtained.

Could you please tell me how to fix this problem?

---

The example that I tested was something like this

```
f<-lm(y∼x1+x2+x3)

intervals(f,level=.95)
```

Comment: `stats::confint(f)` ?

Comment: `methods(intervals)` will show you what types of objects can be used as arguments to `intervals`. Objects of class `'lm'` is not one of them ( and that's what `f` is)

Comment: @DuckPyjamas thank you. It worked.

Comment: @DuckPyjamas Is it possible to calculate a confidence interval of 95% for a mean quantity when x1=some number,x2=xome number, x3=some number? Or another function is required?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I didn't know that. I'll keep in mind next time :)

Comment: @Isa I'm not sure, but perhaps if you use `predict()` then you can just say that the confidence interval around the mean from `confint()` is consistent throughout the entire series.